# HTML code encoded using T-SQL working fine for view report functionality but not for view as pdf, any way to get this resolved?

Tags: html, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

Below is HTML code encoded in T-SQL. All below code is inserted into the temporary table (in a stored procedure) and being returned the whole below output from the stored procedure.

This stored procedure to be used/called from one page of portal .asp page (developed in ASP.net HTML/VBA form) where there is a option provided of view a report and download the same as PDF so issue here is view report is working fine however pdf showing wrong output. The same stored procedure is being called for both functionalities.

Output is showing wrongly in PDF as below

```
number   quant0     price&nbsp
123      2&nbsp     2&nbsp
```

Correct output would be:

```
number   quant0     price&nbsp
123      2          2
```

HTML code which being returned from above stored procedure

```
   <span style="font-style: italic;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">Processed</span></span><hr />
    <table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; border: 0;"><tr><td>
    Some text ABC <br />
    Prepared <span style="font-weight: bold;">Hi there </span> on <span style="font-weight: bold;">04/28/2021</span><hr />To: 3561<hr />
    <hr />
    Set something....<br />
    <small>Type of.... </small><span style="font-weight: bold;"></span><small> Purpose </small><span style="font-weight: bold;">N - Original</span><small> Dated </small><span style="font-weight: bold;">20210428 </span><br /><h3> PURCHASE </h3><br />
    <table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><small> Requested:   </small></td><td>05/14/2021</td></tr></table>
    Instructions<br />
    Entire Transaction.... <br />
    <small>F.O.B. </small><span style="font-weight: bold;"> </span><br />
    <small> To: </small><br />XYZ.... <span style="font-style: italic;">PQRS....</span><br />
    ABCDF....<br />
    none of these<br />
    XYZ 1234... <br />
    NULL
    <small>To</small><br />name of doc... <span style="font-style: italic;">0018424670019</span><br />
    name of person<br />
    name of<br />
    A 95206 <br />
    <small>Vendor: </small><br />name of cust... <span style="font-style: italic;">020000</span><br />
    25vy ...<br />
    pqr... <br />
    <hr />
    <table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 2px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">number</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">QuantO</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Price</span>&nbsp</td><td style="width: 20%;"></td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr></table><table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">049949</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;">40&nbsp</td><td style="width: 20%;">36.00000&nbsp</td><td style="width: 20%;">CA</td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> Code: </td><td class="NoWrap">001</td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> Vendor Item: </td><td class="NoWrap"></td></tr></table>
    <hr />
    <table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 2px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">number</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">QuantO</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Price</span>&nbsp</td><td style="width: 20%;"></td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr></table><table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">096273</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;">40&nbsp</td><td style="width: 20%;">42.40000&nbsp</td><td style="width: 20%;">CA</td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> Code: </td><td class="NoWrap">001111</td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> Vendor Item: </td><td class="NoWrap"></td></tr></table>
    <hr />
    <table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 2px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">number</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">QuantO</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Price</span>&nbsp</td><td style="width: 20%;"></td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr></table><table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">158598</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;">48&nbsp</td><td style="width: 20%;">28.80000&nbsp</td><td style="width: 20%;">CA</td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> Code: </td><td class="NoWrap">001911</td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> Vendor Item: </td><td class="NoWrap"></td></tr></table>
    <hr />
    <table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 2px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">number</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">QuantO</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Price</span>&nbsp</td><td style="width: 20%;"></td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr></table><table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">251856</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;">40&nbsp</td><td style="width: 20%;">54.00000&nbsp</td><td style="width: 20%;">CA</td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> Code: </td><td class="NoWrap">0910</td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> Vendor Item: </td><td class="NoWrap"></td></tr></table>
    <hr />
    <table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 2px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">number</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">QuantO</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Price</span>&nbsp</td><td style="width: 20%;"></td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr></table><table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">252239</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;">40&nbsp</td><td style="width: 20%;">63.60000&nbsp</td><td style="width: 20%;">CA</td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> Code: </td><td class="NoWrap">908</td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> Vendor Item: </td><td class="NoWrap"></td></tr></table>
    </td></tr></table>
```

Comment: It's not clear how you expect raw HTML to download as a PDF and display correctly?

Comment: @TimWilliams-Thanks for checking this out. Yes this is a raw data which is being returned by store proc where one ASP page is consuming this returned data for further manipulations and on same asp page a logic is returned for downloading this report which is not working

Comment: @user8758891 Then the fact that you retrieve this HTML from sql server is irrelevant. It is your ASP code that consumes it, manipulates it, and then saves it as a PDF file that needs your focus. And no one but you knows what "Output is showing wrongly" means. You need to provide code and details for anyone to help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was @nbsp was working on some browser and not on some so added one more @nbsp worked for me